# WPF DatePicker date doesn't switch with culture

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, localization

I actually found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779981/how-to-force-wpf-toolkit-datepicker-to-refresh-in-ui-after-culture-change), but like the OP says it's a hacky solution, and like the votes say not a beautiful one. My program has one window.

I have a UI with 2 possible cultures, de-DE and en-US, and a button that switches the language.

Every text changes when I press that button, only the text in the DatePickers texbox doesn't, until I click on the DatePickers button, then it changes the shown date to the right format (and opens the DatePicker popup).

How can I make the shown date switch with the language? Isn't there some wpf option I can use to make it update the shown date?

Only Binding it has is `SelectedDate="{Binding Path=FileDate, Mode=TwoWay}`, and it works well so far.

I tried doing the following on switch of language, but it doesn't make the text change:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo((string)getSetting("Language"));
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo((string)getSetting("Language"));
FileDate = FileDate; //This one Notifies about the propertychange, so I hoped it would refresh the text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok so I got another idea, and it works great, doesn't feel like a hack, and is easy to do:**

When switching the language, beside setting the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture, I go

```
FileDate = DateTime.Now;
```

That apperently makes the DatePicker realize the Culture has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  answer of [squirrelkiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364057/squirrelkiller) I would like to mention that the DatePicker (.net 4.6.1) also does not automatically take `CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`. It has to be set per Datepicker instance indiviually. I posted this also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996939/wpf-datepicker-date-doesnt-switch-with-culture-plus-firstdayofweek?noredirect=1&lq=1)